# Application works on emulator not on physical device: I can not access the images I defined as URL on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

My application works normally on the emulator, but When I install it on a physical phone, I cannot access the images I defined as URL in Firebase. So when I upload the application to the phone, there are no pictures. Apart from that everything works fine in practice. Is there anything you can recommend me to do? Android version of phone:  `Android 7 API 24.`

this is emulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUacr.png)

this is my phone

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDapk.png)

```
package com.orderfood.teknomerkez.orderfood;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar;
import com.orderfood.teknomerkez.orderfood.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import com.orderfood.teknomerkez.orderfood.Model.Food;
import com.orderfood.teknomerkez.orderfood.ViewHolder.FoodViewHolder;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FoodList extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference foodList;
    private final String REFERENCE = "Food";
    private String FoodId = "FoodId";
    String categoryID = "";
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, FoodViewHolder> adapter;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, FoodViewHolder> searchAdapter;
    List<String> suggestList = new ArrayList<>();
    MaterialSearchBar materialSearchBar;
    private String getCategoryId = "CategoryId";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_list);
        //Firebase
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        foodList = database.getReference(REFERENCE);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_food);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        //get intent
        if (getIntent() != null)
            categoryID = getIntent().getStringExtra(getCategoryId);
        if (!categoryID.isEmpty() && categoryID != null) {
            loadListFood(categoryID);
        }

        //material Search
        materialSearch();
    }

    private void materialSearch() {
        materialSearchBar = findViewById(R.id.searchBar);
        materialSearchBar.setHint("Enter Your Food");
        loadSuggest();
        materialSearchBar.setLastSuggestions(suggestList);
        materialSearchBar.setCardViewElevation(10);
        materialSearchBar.addTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                //when user type something, we will change suggestlist
                List<String> suggest = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String search : suggest) { // loop in suggest list
                    if (search.toLowerCase().contains(materialSearchBar.getText().toLowerCase())) {
                        suggest.add(search);
                    }
                    materialSearchBar.setLastSuggestions(suggest);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
        materialSearchBar.setOnSearchActionListener(new MaterialSearchBar.OnSearchActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSearchStateChanged(boolean enabled) {
                //when search bar is close - restore original adapter
                if (!enabled)
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSearchConfirmed(CharSequence text) {
                //when searhc finish
                startSearch(text);
            }

            @Override
            public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void loadSuggest() {
        foodList.orderByChild("MenuId").equalTo(categoryID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot postSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Food item = postSnapShot.getValue(Food.class);
                    suggestList.add(item.getName());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void startSearch(CharSequence text) {
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("Food")
                .startAt(text.toString())
                .limitToLast(50);

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Food> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Food>().setQuery(query, Food.class).build();
        searchAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, FoodViewHolder>(options)
        {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public FoodViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.food_item, parent,false);
                return new FoodViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FoodViewHolder viewHolder, int position, @NonNull Food model) {
                viewHolder.food_name.setText(model.getName());
                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage())
                        .into(viewHolder.food_image);
                final Food local = model;
                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        Toast.makeText(FoodList.this, "" + local.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //go food
                        Intent foodDetail = new Intent(FoodList.this, FoodDetail.class);
                        foodDetail.putExtra(FoodId, searchAdapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                        startActivity(foodDetail);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(searchAdapter); //set adapter for recycler view  is search result
    }


    private void loadListFood(String categoryID) {
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("Food")
                .child(categoryID);

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Food> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Food>().setQuery(query,Food.class).build();
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, FoodViewHolder>(options) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public FoodViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.food_item, parent,false);
                return new FoodViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FoodViewHolder viewHolder, int position, @NonNull Food model) {
                viewHolder.food_name.setText(model.getName());
                Log.d("TAG", model.getName());
                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage())
                        .into(viewHolder.food_image);
                final Food local = model;
                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        Toast.makeText(FoodList.this, "" + local.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //go food
                        Intent foodDetail = new Intent(FoodList.this, FoodDetail.class);
                        //foodDetail.putExtra("FoodId", adapter.getItem(position).getFoodId());
                        foodDetail.putExtra("FoodId", String.valueOf(position));
                        foodDetail.putExtra("CategoryID", adapter.getItem(position).getMenuId());
                        foodDetail.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(foodDetail);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        Log.d("TAG", "" + adapter.getItemCount());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give the error log if any .. Or part of your code..

Comment: I have editted my question.

Comment: Are you installed the app after signing the apk

Comment: Can you specify the image url

Comment: "https://www.nusretusta.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/%C3%96zel-Kar%C4%B1%C5%9F%C4%B1k-Kebap-720x320.jpg"

Comment: One way to debug is to connect your device to your laptop with USB and try to run application on that device (from Android Studio though) to get the logs. Then check what's going wrong.

Comment: One more thing, I hope you have requested internet permission (`android.permission.INTERNET`) in manifest file!

Comment: Yeah, I have requested internet permission. It already works on emulator. Which one segment I need to check from debug console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. Because I am not going to change images that I want to see, I have customize model classes variables. I have changed like this;

from

```
private String Image;
```

to

```
public String Image;
```

I  was using getter and setter methods to see Images. After that I have changed FoodList adapter methods like this;

```
Picasso p = Picasso.get();
 p.load(model.Image).into(viewHolder.food_image);
```

As you can see I have also updated Picasso. I have used the latest version. It is used `get()` instead of `with()`. It doesnt need `getBaseContext()`.

As I told you that I am not going to change images. So I can use `model.Image` If your images are changeable, you need to use getter and setter methods as you know.

Answer (score 0):

In your phone 
follow this steps
go to settings 
then apps/installed app....and search your app
then click open
and in App Permission option allow all permission
Hope its Works